# jquery .html load external file through object data is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying the demo solution like below

```
$("#loadExtPage01").html(<object data="https://system.netsuite.com/pages/customerlogin.jsp?country=US" />);
```

It is working instead of the object data, when i try to use my own external file url its not working(loading)?

i.e:

```
$("#loadExtPage01").html(<object data="http://gmovdevk2pocapp:81/Runtime/Runtime/Form/MarketingServiceTicketCreateEditForm?FarmId=1&ServiceTicketTaskId=21&ServiceTicketId=7&ServiceTypeId=2" />);
```

Any ideas / solutions ?

Comment: Your second URL is not even getting loaded in browser. Please check if the url is correct. :)

Comment: @: Maverick - But the "This page can’t be displayed" error message is also not showing inside the div where i am loading, whereas if i used iframe it showing loading and showing the browser information like "This page can’t be displayed"...why ?

Comment: Tarun Pai - so what is another solution to load the external url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to wrap the code in a string :)

```
$("#loadExtPage01").html("<object data='https://system.netsuite.com/pages/customerlogin.jsp?country=US'/>");
```

The method expects a string, what you were doing is actually invalid because you're writing javascript not html :D

If you need it you can add some fallback html like this:

```
$("#loadExtPage01").html("<object data='URL'>could not load</object>")
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/m69nR/1/)

If the resource can't be obtained, whatever is inside the `object` tag will be shown.

You could also use an iframe, which could be a more appropriate solution:

```
<iframe src="https://system.netsuite.com/pages/customerlogin.jsp?country=US"></iframe>
```

Put that in your html, no need for javascript in this case. If not found you'll get the native resolution error of your browser, I tried it myself using your localhost url:

http://jsfiddle.net/m69nR/

Comment: Jamie: I already tried that as well, not work with my URL, please check once :(  $("#loadExtPage01").html("<object data='http://gmovdevk2pocapp:81/Runtime/Runtime/Form/MarketingServiceTicketCreateEditForm?FarmId=1&ServiceTicketTaskId=21&ServiceTicketId=7&ServiceTypeId=2'/>");

Comment: I see what you mean, so the second url doesn't work for you either, but you want some kind of "Unable to resolve..." message for reassurance or something? Why don't you use and iframe? I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Jaime Gomez: I don't want to use iframe, because it affect my another navigation futionality,i.e basically performance issue with loading dynamic other data...

Comment: Then don't worry, the method works, it's just that since the address can't be resolved there's no actual html for jquery to show; just add a border, some static size so the box is there, and load it. You could also add some fallback html, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/m69nR/1/

Answer (score 0):

what is also important is that you allow iframing.

apache will block iframing when the security is set like this:

```
 Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS DENY
```

use this instead:

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```